# Content spilling out of table cell when using percentage

Tags: css, cross-browser

Depending on which browser you use, the following will display differently:

```css
.table1 td {
  padding: 0 30%;
  border:1px solid;
}
.table2 td {
  padding: 0 30px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1"><tr><td>Text</td></tr></table>
<table class="table2"><tr><td>Text</td></tr></table>
```

I'd expect `table1` to behave like `table2`, but it does not in Firefox 36. Chrome also doesn't add a right side padding to the cells, but at least it's increasing the table's width (somewhat).

Is that a bug or are the other browsers doing something wrong? Am I missing something?

Can I achieve the desired behaviour without using absolute units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following simple tables.  In the first two cases, I spaced out the text and added 30% and 0% padding respectively.

In `.table1`, the text wraps around after two characters and you see the 30% padding on the left and right. Note the width of the table.

Now, look at `.table1a`, in this case 0% padding.  Note that the width of the table is the same as the first example, which is just wide enough to contain the text on a single line, as expected.

The table layout algorithm first determines the width of the table based on the content, in this case, single line of characters.  After the width is computed, the 30% padding is computed and applied to the table cell, which is what you see in the top example

In your original example, the text was a single word, and could not wrap around a second line.  This caused an overflow condition, and the text was positioned to the left with 30% padding, but, it was overflowing to the right and jutting out over the right padding and the right edge/border of the table.

This is proper table layout behavior, just not overly intuitive.

In the final case, `.table2`, since you specified 30px left/right padding, the table layout algorithm first adds the left/right 30px padding to the cell width along with the computed length of the text, and this in turn determines the overall width of the table.

As a final note, perhaps the 30% padding in the first two cases could have been added to the overall width of the table, but a decision was made to keep the overall width to be that computed for the contained text.  I don't have a definitive answer as to why the CSS specification evolved along this line.

```css
.table1 td {
  padding: 0 30%;
  border:1px solid;
}
.table1a td {
  padding: 0 0%;
  border:1px solid;
}
.table2 td {
  padding: 0 30px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1"><tr><td>T e x t 1 </td></tr></table>
<table class="table1a"><tr><td>T e x t 1 </td></tr></table>
<table class="table2"><tr><td>Text 2</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table1 td {
  width:100px;
  padding:0 30%;
  border:1px solid;
}
.table2 td {
  padding: 0 30px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1"><tr><td>Text1</td></tr></table>
<table class="table2"><tr><td>Text</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Please set width of the table1 because padding is the percent of the width of the containing element.